# Having trouble installing tensorflow on rstudio

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am fairly new to R studio, any help would be appreciated. I am installing r studio on my Mac, I am getting an error while trying to install tensorflow

> devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
>
> library(tensorflow)
>
> install_tensorflow()

I get this error

Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available.

Execute the following at a terminal to install the prerequisites:

$ sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade virtualenv

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: have you tried installing `pip` and upgrading to `virtualenv` just like it recommends?

Answer (score 0):

From the official Rstudio [website](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/installation.html):

> TensorFlow is distributed as a Python package and so needs to be
>   installed within a Python environment on your system. By default, the
>   install_tensorflow() function attempts to install TensorFlow within
>   it’s own isolated Python environment (“r-tensorflow”).

And the python installation mostly relies on pip for installing it's dependencies. As the error message suggests, install pip and upgrade the `virtualenv` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I can't seem to find an installation guide for pip and how to upgrade my virtualenv. Thanks for your help btw I am really new to all of this.

Comment: I think as the error message said, try directly running the commands and see what happens. Without further information on your environment, it's difficult to comment. Also, there are lot  of pip installation tutorials available online, you can check that also.